# log4j:WARN Unrecognized element rollingPolicy

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I had this warning in log when my application was starting

```
log4j:WARN Unrecognized element rollingPolicy
```

tried to Google for answers, but adding apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar didn't helped me.

I'm using `slf4j-log4j12 1.7.2` with `log4j 1.2.17`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of rollingPolicy I used DailyRollingFileAppender and no extras jar is needed.

```xml
<appender name="rollingLog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/rolling.log" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] [%c] %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
</appender>
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use the extras but make sure to change log4j.xml appender line to:

```
<appender name="ROLL" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
```

and do away with it.