# log4j:WARN No such property [rollingPolicy] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, apache-zookeeper

I am using log4j-1.2.16.jar and apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar.

I want to enable rolling files with date appended to the filename. But showing this errot and files are not rotating as expected.

My log4j.properties file looks like this.

```
zookeeper.root.logger=DEBUG, ROLLINGFILE
zookeeper.console.threshold=DEBUG
zookeeper.log.dir=/path/to/logs
zookeeper.log.file=zookeeper.log
zookeeper.log.threshold=DEBUG
zookeeper.tracelog.dir=.
zookeeper.tracelog.file=zookeeper_trace.log
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.Threshold=${zookeeper.log.threshold}
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.File=${zookeeper.log.dir}/${zookeeper.log.file}
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=${zookeeper.log.dir}/app%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxFileSize=20KB
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=100000
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [myid:%X{myid}] - %-5p [%t:%C{1}@%L] - %m%n
```

Comment: This may only be available from `1.2.17`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6037141/14955  And the versions of these two jar files should be aligned.

Comment: @Thilo Same issue exists even if I use log4j-1.2.17.jar and apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar.

Comment: Try `DailyRollingFileAppender` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18920684/14955

Comment: @Thil `DailyRollingFileAppender ` does not rotate files by size right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Managed to fix it. The problem was with `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`
. And it worked once I change it to`org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`

```
zookeeper.root.logger=DEBUG, ROLLINGFILE
zookeeper.console.threshold=DEBUG
zookeeper.log.dir=/path/to/logs
zookeeper.log.file=zookeeper.log
zookeeper.log.threshold=DEBUG
zookeeper.tracelog.dir=.
zookeeper.tracelog.file=zookeeper_trace.log
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.Threshold=${zookeeper.log.threshold}
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.File=${zookeeper.log.dir}/${zookeeper.log.file}
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=${zookeeper.log.dir}/app%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxFileSize=20KB
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=100000
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [myid:%X{myid}] - %-5p [%t:%C{1}@%L] - %m%n
```

Comment: Looking at the code of org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender, this solution wouldn't have worked. While the class have the rollingPolicy & rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern fields, it doesn't have MaxFileSize & MaxBackupIndex files. Did you check the error log?

It is opposite in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender class. It just doesn't come in two flavors.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code of *org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender* which is from a separate *apache-log4j-extras* package, this solution wouldn't have worked. While the class have the *rollingPolicy & rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern* fields, it doesn't have *maxFileSize* & *maxBackupIndex* fields. Did you check the error log?

It is opposite in *org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender* class. It has the *MaxFileSize* & *maxBackupIndex* fields but not *rollingPolicy* & *rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern* fields. It just doesn't come in two flavors.